# Including datanodes in html by hiding : good idea?

Tags: jquery, html, xhtml

I would like to add data to an html page that will only be showed dynamically (by means of jquery).  The data is xml (so in fact a part of the html dom).

Now I do it by hiding it by css (`.data { display:none; }`) with html like :

```
<div id="section1">
<h2>Section 1</h2>
    <p>A visible paragraph </p>
    <!-- data that has to do with section 1 -->
    <data class="data">
       <eg1>some data</eg1>
       <eg2>more data</eg2>
    </data>
</div>
```

The data is not shown and can be easily reached by jquery.

While this seems to work fine, I want to know now, early in the process,  if this way of working has some drawbacks I'm not thinking of now...

UPDATE :

Of course it's about non-html tags also. But I could use

```
<div class="data">    
<div class="eg1>
```

just as easily : but even then, the question remains.

Thanks for all input!

Comment: voted up for the good question. This might be a wiki someday

Answer (score 1):

The drawback is having no non-js fallback. For robust code what you would do is create the static HTML so that everything is displayed. And then you use Javascript to hide the "hidden" data and allow the user to show it again via links/fns/whatever.

This is useful because users with no Javascript can still see all the content as well as search engine crawlers (or other crawlers/bots) who interpret visibility as well may find it useful.

Comment: Then you’re good to go. Remember that it’s still in the source though. Ppl may inspect it, as well as crawlers. Alternative would be asynchronous JS, loading data later on via XHR.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad idea.
Good idea would be using a form

```
<form name="data">
<input type="hidden" name="eg1" value="Some data" />
<input type="hidden" name="eg2" value="Some data" />
</form>
```

You can easily access it via jQuery by using `document.data.eg1` and `document.data.eg2` etc

Once you need to show data, fetch it via jQuery and populate the divs.

Edit:
If you need to put it in markup instead of hidden input fields, use a definition list

```
<dl>
   <dt>eg1</dt><dd>Somedata</dd>
   <dt>eg2</dt><dd>Somedata</dd>
   <dt>eg3</dt><dd>Somedata</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: because when a search engine reads your page, it wont give the css much preference. It will read the data and load it. While having it as params instead of HTML text will make sure search engines treat it nicely.

Comment: Still, hidden input fields may or may not be ignored by crawlers. It’s not a very robust solution. It also adds overhead. And just because crawlers will index it does not mean that’s bad. The question author didn’t say anything about hiding the data from everyone and everything by default. If he wants to do that, it should not be in the source at all but fetched asynchronously later on via JS.

Comment: @Kissaki... If at all we need to put data in markup, then we should use a Definition List instead of DIVS or non-standard markup elements

Comment: @Kissaki : why shouldn't it be in the source?  The overhead is mininmal (like 2%), but if it really is a bad idea : I won't do it, I just want to know why.

Comment: It’s a matter on where you want your data, and where you don’t want it. If it’s in the source, ppl can inspect and read it, as well as bots, crawlers etc. If that doesn’t matter to you, no problem with code in there. Entirely depends on why you want to hide the data anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using jQuery, you should go for `jQuery.data()` (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) which stores the data in the viewmodel.

You can do:

```
jQuery.data('myvar', 'myvalue');
```

and then fetch it back simply by using

```
var myval = jQuery.data('myvar');
```

You can also attach the data to an element in your dom (it will still not be visible):

```
$('#my-data-div').data('whatever', 'somevalue');
```

and retrieve it:

```
var myval = $('#my-data-div').data('whatever');
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Similar; you may want to use the `data-` attributes. See http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Comment: @Peter The data-attributes are of HTML5 spec, yes, but they will work just fine with any website and jQuery.  You can basically put whatever you want inside a tag. Only issue with it is that it wont validate against older HTML Standards...